# Tools to study level sets of Lebesgue function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Given $u\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)$ with compact support, are there nice tools to study the level sets $$K: = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^N : u(x) = \|u\|_\infty \text{ a.e.}\}.$$
The main problem is $K$ being Lebesgue null set. And I will give some motivation about this problem.

Looking at the following limit 
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \bigg(\frac{|u|} {\|u\|_p}\bigg)^p d\mu = \lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} 1 = 1.$$

When $K$ defined as above, and with $\mu(K) >0$, we have 
$$1 = \lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \bigg(\frac{|u|} {\|u\|_p}\bigg)^p d\mu = \lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} \int_{K} \bigg(\frac{|u|} {\|u\|_p}\bigg)^p d\mu+ \lim_{p\rightarrow \infty}\int_{K^c} \bigg(\frac{|u|} {\|u\|_p}\bigg)^p d\mu$$
the first integral over $K$ converges to 
$$\frac{1}{\mu(K)} \int_{K} 1 d\mu = 1,$$ 
therefore the limit of the second integral over $K^c$ has to be zero
$$ \lim_{p\rightarrow \infty}\int_{K^c} \bigg(\frac{|u|} {\|u\|_p}\bigg)^p d\mu = 0. \quad\quad (\star)$$

However when $\mu(K) = 0$, we have

$$1 = \lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \bigg(\frac{|u|} {\|u\|_p}\bigg)^p d\mu = \lim_{p\rightarrow \infty}\int_{K^c} \bigg(\frac{|u|} {\|u\|_p}\bigg)^p d\mu = 1$$
which is different from $(\star)$ above.

And I am trying figure out why would this happen, the integral over $K^c$ changes its value in the limit.

Comment: I can't get what your "a.e." means inside the definition of $K$.  What is more, $u(x)$ can equal $||u||_\infty$ outside a null set:  for example, if $u$ is a constant function, or more generally one that takes its maximum value on a non-null set.

Comment: It may depend on the dots "..." inside the integral. There is a very nice answer for your question in the context of multifractal analysis, *depending* on what you may assume. In fact even null sets may be quite large from other points of view (not topological point of view, that is essentially trivial).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I edited the post to give more info about this problem